# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame when there is no copy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently getting the warning

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

on this line:

```
  df["next"] = df[
    "next"] * df["curr"].map(lookup)
```

I'm confused where the "a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe" is coming from? from what I can see, the LHS is a reference to the column in `df`, so there are no copies here?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, the warning message suggests that the left-hand side of the assignment operation (df["next"]) is a copy of a slice of the original DataFrame. This can happen when you use chained indexing operations like df[...], which may return a copy of the data instead of a reference to the original DataFrame.

To avoid this warning and ensure that you're modifying the original DataFrame, you can use the loc accessor as suggested in the warning message. Try this:

```
df.loc[:, "next"] = df["next"] * df["curr"].map(lookup)
```

Comment: I see, but in my particular case, it should always modify the original dataframe right?

Comment: By default, indexing operations on a DataFrame return a view of the data, rather than a copy

Comment: And a view is just a reference right? I guess I don't understand why python can't pick up that this is not a copy